# How do I commit changes to Plone package hosted on github?

Tags: plone

I want to commit to a Plone package. Do I include it with mr.developer? If yes, the code is in buildout-folder/src. After I made my changes, how do I commit with my existing github account? Should I use something different than mr.developer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a fork of the package in your github account, then using `mr.developer` is an excellent way to make local changes.

Just use normal git tools. The repository is indeed located in the `src/` directory, just cd to it and use a normal git workflow. Then use GitHub to issue a pull request to the original package for your changes.

All `mr.developer` does is make it easier to switch buildout to use the development egg stored in `src/` and to make the workflow of working with 1 or more repositories for eggs-under-development. It doesn't require you to do anything special with a version-control managed package.

Comment: Ok. So the workflow is: Fork on Github. Use this to include in buildout via mr.developer. make changes. commit via command-line to github. if super dangerous killer bug: on github issue a pull request.  Like this?